# How do I examine the Crime Scene during the "Blood on Ice" quest in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am trying to solve the "Blood on the ice"-quest and am told to examine the crime scene. But I cannot find any trigger to activate or object to collect.

What am I supposed to find/do here?

Comment: Use the [evidence scanner](http://guides.gamepressure.com/batmanarkhamcity/guide.asp?ID=12552) on your belt.

Comment: @NickT ummmmm you know this is skyrim right?

Comment: [That's the joke.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DontExplainTheJoke)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are supposed to follow the trail of blood

> It will eventually lead to a house where you can find various pieces of evidence.

Comment: Huh. One of those I-should-have-found-out-myself-things; but damn, was that arrow pointing on the crime scene misleading ;)

Comment: Oh wow. I gave up on this quest because I thought it was bugged. Trying this later.

Comment: Many quests are better with the arrows turned off, and then some are actually *easier* with them off!

Comment: Follow the blood...follow the red blood trail oh follow follow follow follow...follow the trail of blood...

Comment: Even after reading this I couldn't work put where the blood trail led. Damn snow

Comment: @SteveGreatrex take a peek at Johnny's answer, it tells you exactly where to go.

Comment: The blood trail didn't appear for me for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the blood trail to Hjerim (the name of the house) and pick the lock (master). You can also go to the steward and he will tell you where to get the key to the house.

Comment: You don't need to pick the lock, if you go back to the steward, he will tell you who to talk to in order to get the key.

Comment: I finally found the building and tried to pick that lock and went through 18 picks... I never even found the spot I needed to rotate the dang thing. Maybe because Im just 18 LP... Must enchant everything with 20% buff to lock pick. :P Where is that steward?

Comment: He is In The palace of kings. :)

Comment: Didn’t need to pick the lock, and it’s unclear since the quest appears unfulfilled. Once you get the journals from the house, go see the stewards, the quest will be done!

Answer (score 3):

I watched this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xrhZW_qCxE) and followed that exact path to reach the clue house as I was not able to find it even after reading the spoiler in the accepted answer.

If you are running Skyrim on a seven year old laptop using a dozen **performance mods**, most likely, **you won't see the blood stains**.

Comment: Could you please add a link to said youtube video?

Comment: added yt video link :)