# How can I reset the Blood on the Ice quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was roaming around Windhelm and I went into a house and it started the Blood on the Ice quest. It just has a blank desk and 1 objective that says "Look for clues." It looks like Susanna has already been murdered.

I'm playing Skyrim Legendary Edition with no mods. How can I fix the quest?

Comment: If it started the quest Blood on Ice, then your question title could be a bit misleading. You can check [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39245/how-do-i-examine-the-crime-scene-during-the-blood-on-ice-quest-in-skyrim) on how to examine the crime scene and move further.

Comment: @LoreFriendly "Look For Clues" is inside the house, not at the crime scene. They already made it to the house.

Comment: Most related question I can find: [Blood on the Ice - No interaction with the clues in Hjerim possible](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/47226/108003). Surprised there's no duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I start the Blood on the Ice quest?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41219/how-can-i-start-the-blood-on-the-ice-quest)

Comment: @Jim Jones That question is diffrent because he hasent had the quest triggered, no one had evan murded susanna yet. Mine is diffrent because sussana was already murdered. The event didnt happen tho and my quest is bugged.

Comment: You quest is not bugged.  [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood_on_the_Ice#How_to_Start_the_Quest) has more details.  In short, proceed from the house investigation and continue from there as normal.

You can't reset the quest.  Don't mess around with the console to reset it.  This specific quest has a lot of complex triggers, and it involves special scripts in a guard.  If you force a reset, it will most likely be impossible to complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pick up the following items:

- The Butcher's Journal #1 (can be found in the chest next to the wall near the entrance)
- The Butcher's Journal #2 (can be found on the altar)
- The Strange Amulet and pamphlets (which are on the small dresser)

[Source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_on_the_Ice)

Comment: what do i do next? will the quest automaticly complete itself?

Comment: @TomRibbertry the quest doesn't end there. I can't exactly remember what comes next (I played this quest quite a while ago), but according to the wiki you should go speak to Jorleif (the steward).

Comment: ok thx @angussidney